# Simulate parallel behaviour

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to go further in understanding JS. I've tried to implement something to make parallel function calls:

```
console.log(0);
setTimeout(function () { render('header', 10000000); }, 0);
console.log(1);
setTimeout(function () { render('content', 10000); }, 0);
console.log(2);
setTimeout(function () { render('footer', 100); }, 0);
console.log(3);

function render (element, iteration) {
  console.log('render', element);

  // Hard work
  for(var i=0 ; i < iteration; i++) {
    Math.cbrt(i);
  }

  console.log('rendered', element);
}
```

However, it's always rendering the same thing:

```
0
1
2
3
render header
rendered header
render content
rendered content
render footer
rendered footer
```

And I don't really understand why. I don't want to use premises or any other library.

What's happening behind this magic?

Comment: Javascript is a single-thread language.You should implement something like a thread dispatcher to achieve what you want. What do you want to achieve in this way?

Comment: Perhaps you might understand better if you put another `console.log` directly after the `setTimeout` calls, and observe the output. JavaScript always executes to completion before moving on. This means that JavaScript doesn't have data races, or other synchronization issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS is still single threaded. `setTimeout` doesn't not start another thread.
You add 3 callback functions using `setTimeout` and tell each to run 0ms from now. They all go into a queue of things that need to run. Then they are individually run on the same thread, so the first "render header" function still blocks the next callback from being taken off the queue of functions to run.

[HTML web workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) might be something you could use to do this, but I've never used them myself.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses a single thread to execute your code. If you use `setTimeout` then there is added an entry to the event loop as soon as it is ready to be processed. As you didn't specify a delay the entry is created directly but it gets only executed once your initial code which creates the entries completed. See this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
page for details about it.